# Redirect FROM stderr to another file descriptor

Tags: c++, unix, pipe, stderr, dup2

My program calls library functions which print to stderr. I want to intervene so that all write calls to file descriptor #2 will instead get sent to somewhere else.

Here is my first attempt:

```
bool redirect_stderr (int fd)
{
    return dup2 (2, fd) > 0;
}
```

Here, fd was successfully obtained from `open("/foo/bar",O_APPEND|O_CREAT)`

After this function returns true, `std::cerr<<"blah"` goes to the terminal and not to the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Thanks, larsmans, but I'm not there yet...

```
void redirect_stderr_to (const char * output_file)
{
    int fd = open (output_file, O_APPEND | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    if (fd < 0) {
        throw RUNTIME_ERROR;
    }
    else {
        if (-1 == dup2 (fd, STDERR_FILENO))
            throw RUNTIME_ERROR;

        std :: cout << (std::cerr ? "Fine\n" : "Bad\n");
        char x [100];
        std :: cerr
            << "Output to " << getcwd (x, 100) << " / " << output_file
            <<  " yields " << fd << " errno: " << errno << "\n";
        std :: cout << (std::cerr ? "Fine\n" : "Bad\n");
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
Fine
Bad
```

to stdout and the given file is empty. (It is correctly created if it doesn't exist.)

Comment: Please accept some answers before you post your next question. Click the checkmark next to the best answer for your previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reversed the arguments: it's

```
dup2(from_fd, to_fd)
```

i.e.

```
dup2(fd, 2)
```

(see [POSIX.2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) or your manpages.)

Comment: man page says `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);` and 2 is the old fd, no?

Comment: No: `oldfd` is the fd copied from, and `newfd` is the fd copied to. (`oldfd` and `newfd` aren't very good names for the arguments. Is that a Linux manpage?)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: You could even achieve your goal with `freopen(name, mode, stderr)`, which is a Standard/ANSI/ISO C89 and C99 function.