# How can I turn libavformat error messages off

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat, libav

By default, libavformat writes error messages to `stderr`, Like:

`Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate`

How can I turn it off? or better yet, pipe it to my own neat logging function?

**Edit:** Redirecting stderr to somewhere else is not acceptable since I need it for other logging purposes, I just want libavformat to not write to it.

Comment: See either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095839/redirect-from-stderr-to-another-file-descriptor or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573724/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-to-some-visible-display-in-a-windows-application

Comment: I don't want to redirect the whole output of stderr of the program, I have my logging functions writing to it in a neat formatted manner. I'd just like libavformat to not write to it.

Comment: What exactly writes to stderr? This is the 1st time that I hear libavcodec library sends errors to stderr (my experience with that library is not big).

Comment: I'm not really sure. It throws error messages haphazardly like the one I mentioned above. It might even be libavcodec and not libavformat. It's hard to track down since no further information is given.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking through the code, it appears you can change the behavior by writing your own callback function for the `av_log` function.

From the description of this function in [libavutil/log.h](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob_plain;f=libavutil/log.h;hb=HEAD):

> Send the specified message to the log if the level is less than or equal
>   to the current av_log_level. By default, all logging messages are sent to
>   stderr. **This behavior can be altered by setting a different av_vlog callback
>   function.**

The API provides a function that will allow you to define your own callback:

```
void av_log_set_callback(void (*)(void*, int, const char*, va_list));
```

In your case, you could write a simple callback function that discards the messages altogether (or redirects them to a dedicated log, etc.) without tainting your `stderr` stream.

Comment: Beat me to it. You can also use `av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET)` to quiet all logging.

Answer (score 9):

Give `av_log_set_level(level)` a try!

Answer (score 5):

1. include this header file

   ```
   #include <libavutil/log.h>
   ```
2. add this code will disable the log

   ```
   av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect them to a custom file, **it will redirect all cerr entry**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream file("file.txt");

  streambuf *old_cerr = cerr.rdbuf();

  cerr.rdbuf (file.rdbuf());

  cerr << "test test test" << endl; // writes to file.txt

  // ...

  cerr.rdbuf (old_cerr); // restore orginal cerr

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** After editing the question, i warn about above code that it will redirect all `cerr` entry stream to `file.txt`

I'm not familiar with libavformat, but if its code is unchangeable, you can temporary redirect `cerr` to a file before calling library's api and redirect it to original `cerr` again.(However this is ugly way)

Comment: ... and all other `cerr` messages. I don't think that's what OP wanted.