# FFMpeg for IOS - Disabling Log Levels

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I have compiled ffmpeg for ios. The configuration for compiling, i have borrowed from kxmovie's Rake file.

Everything works fine, but i would like to disable all the debug messages showed in console by the decoder.

How can i achieve this. I believe it should be the ffmpeg is compiled, but am not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

configure command:

> ./configure --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver
>   --disable-ffprobe --disable-doc --disable-bzlib --target-os=darwin --enable-cross-compile --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --assert-level=2 --disable-mmx --arch=i386 --cpu=i386 --extra-ldflags='-arch i386' --extra-cflags='-arch i386' --disable-asm --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
>   --as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc'
>   --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
>   --extra-ldflags=-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/system

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set [-loglevel](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options) to quiet?  I'm not sure there is a compile option and even if there is, it will make debugging harder since you'll need a different ffmpeg binary for debugging.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,
Eventually i would need to disable debugging, once i am satisfied with the functionality. 
There is no configure option called loglevel, ./configure --help | grep log returned
  --logfile=FILE           log tests and output to FILE [config.log]
  --disable-logging        do not log configure debug information

Comment: Not config, runtime.  You can set it with the c function if you are using it as a lib, or runtime argument if you are spawning it

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786802/how-can-i-turn-libavformat-error-messages-off if you are using it as a lib

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that post out. I will try it out and see what i can do. I will update this thread as soon as i can. Thanks jeremy

Comment: i have tried setting the log level by av_log_set_level(0), but nothing seems to change anything.

Comment: Quiet is -8 (better yet AV_LOG_QUIET), 0 is panic (which should have very little output...) [loglevels](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__log__constants.html#gad172eacfed8653e454c6fdcbe53baab3)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40992/discussion-between-veeru-and-jeremy)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out jeremy(my stupid php brain said, it should be 0). I have changed it to -8. However nothing seems to have changed, is till see debug messages like "desync audio (outrun) wait 0.0000 79393.0156"