# How to disable printing video info in ffmpeg library?

Tags: ffmpeg

Each time when I run my c code written with ffmpeg library, there is always some lengthy video info output in my console as follows:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MVI_9359.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    creation_time   : 2012-12-11 19:55:15
  Duration: 00:00:53.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 47283 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 1920x1080, 45744 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-12-11 19:55:15
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-12-11 19:55:15
```

How can I disable this output? I don't need it!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786802/how-can-i-turn-libavformat-error-messages-off). Your level should be 24 or lower.

Comment: av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET) does the magic