# How do I get warn()'s output into a string?

Tags: c++, error-handling, bsd

I'm using the non-standard function `warn()` (provided by BSD) to output an error message if a file can't be opened, like so:

```
std::string path = get_path() ;
std::ifstream file(path) ;
if (file.is_open()) { /* do something */ }
else {
    warn("%s", path.c_str()) ;
    // uses errno to figure out what the error was and outputs it nicely along with the filename
}
```

That's all very well for outputting it, but what if I want to use the entire string somewhere else, in addition to printing it? The `warn()` functions don't seem to have a form that writes the error to a string. I've tried rolling my own, but it seems awfully cumbersome in comparison (besides not getting the program's name):

```
this->foo((boost::format("%s: %s") % path % strerror(errno)).str()) ;
```

So how do I get `warn()`'s output as a string?

Comment: Where does '`warn` come from? It certainly is not a standard c++ function, so maybe the documentation of the API you use it from helps more...

Comment: @PlasmaHH It's, um, a standard C function?

Comment: @BlacklightShining: It, um, is not.

Comment: @BlacklightShining: It's, um, not.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Its manual page says it's in the standard C library…

Comment: @BlacklightShining: Which section and paragraph of the standard mentions it?

Comment: @BlacklightShining: At which manual page are you looking?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `err(3)`—there's about a dozen functions dealing with formatted error messages.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I couldn't tell you. o.o If there's a better way to be printing error messages, I'm open to switching…

Comment: @BlacklightShining "These functions are nonstandard BSD extensions."

Comment: @BlacklightShining: When you claim they are standard C, you better should. Tthere are many, depending on your exact requirements, if you want format strings then wrapping up boost::format in variadic templates seems to be a good idea to me.

Comment: @BlacklightShining I see no mention of the C standard library in `err(3)`. This appears to be a BSD function. Anyway, the answer is what you already wrote.

Answer (score 1):

`warn` puts its output on the standard error output. So you would have to create a mechanism to redirect standard error output to a location that you can read back into a string. The most straight forward way may be to redirect standard error to a file, and then read the file back as a string. You could, for instance, try to use `dup2()` to accomplish this (as explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095839/redirect-from-stderr-to-another-file-descriptor)).

However, wrapping your own version of `warn` is probably a better choice. You may consider the C `vsnprintf()` function to implement it, though. There are answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69738/315052) that address both using `boost::format` and `vsnprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right — there's no `sprintf` analog (i.e. that is, no hypothetical `swarn` function).

Your approach seems viable.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your gyrations produce a result similar to:

```
path + ": " +  strerror(errno);
```

At a guess, the "program's name" that it's including is probably just `argv[0]`, so you could apparently produce a roughly equivalent of your `warn` that just returns a `std::string` with something on this general order:

```
std::string warn_s(std::string const &path) { 
    char *pname = strrchr(argv[0], '/');
    if (pname == NULL)
        pname = argv[0];
    return path + pname + ":  " + strerror(errno);
}
```

The major difficulty here is that `argv` is local to `main`, so you'll probably need to either save it into an accessible location in main, or else use some non-standard mechanism to re-retrieve that data in your function.

Unfortunately, the documentation for `warn` I was able to find was poor enough that a bit of testing/trial and error will probably be needed if you want to duplicate its output precisely.